# Type of return data in API platform

Tags: api-platform.com

I have a problem of changing types of returned data in API platform:
I have an entity:

```
final class ModelClass
{
    /**
     * @var float
     */
    public $total;
}
```

And a configuration:

```
ModelClass:
  properties:
    total:
      attributes:
        swagger_context:
          type: float
```

And Controller:

```
public function __invoke(CustomRequest $request): Paginator
{
    return $this->service->getTotals($request);
}
```

The return of this is Paginator, which holds custom doctrine query, result of which looks like this:

```
{
    "@type": "hydra:Collection",
    "hydra:member": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "total": "120.00",
        },
    ]
}
```

As you see, total is a string (because in the result of query it is a string). What i want it to be: a float: "total": 120.00. And what i would also like to be able to do, is to format it differently, for example separator sign ',' instead '.'
I didnt find in documentation how to do it. Is it a missing documentation or missing feature?

I would expect that API platform reads DocBlock to understand the type of Model. And i think that there is some intercept mechanism after query is executed, but before response is sent back to client, so i could change format/type.
Thank you.